# Javascript (ajax GET request) weird characters in browsers (IE, Firefox etc)

Tags: javascript, ajax, unicode, character-encoding

I am using IIS server, and writing few test pages, with just JavaScript.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", encodeURIComponent(foo), true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    xmlhttp.send();
```

This xmlHttp request gets the content of a text file (saved in unicode format). While I am able to get the content of file, but some characters like ' look weird with question mark tag.

In response header I could see:

```
Content Type: application/x-javascript
```

The page in which, this data in getting updated has meta tag as follows :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Thanks for time.

Comment: What is the request url?

Comment: local machine only http://127.0.0.1:9090/#